# Determine whether permutation of the digits of a number is prime

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test

Given a number $m$ in decimal representation.
I want to find a permutation of the digits of $m$, so it is prime.
(Or output that there exists none)
Do i have in the worst case check every possible permutation or is there a faster approach (for example polynominal time approach)?

Comment: It's easy to eliminate multiples of $3$.

Comment: Well, you can eliminate numbers ending in $0,2,4,5,6,$ or $8$. And you can eliminate multiples of $3$, as @user208259 suggests. But I don't think you can do much better than this $-$ you basically have to try all permutations, apart from the few ruled out by these tests.

Comment: Just a very trivial observation. If the number of digits is $d$, you don't really have to try all $d!$ permutations. rather, if $d_{i}$ is the number of digits equal to $i$, for $0 \le i < 10$, you have *"only"* to try $d!/(d_{0}! d_{1}! \dots d_{9}!)$ permutations, a multinomial coefficient.

Comment: If the given number is divisible by $3$, EVERY permutation is divisible by $3$, if the given number is not divisible by $3$, then NO permutation is divisble by $3$,so there is no need for an elimination of the multiples of $3$. In general, it will be necessary to check every number ending in a $1,3,7$ or $9$, unless the given number is divisible by $3$.

Comment: But with trial division, you can rule out some permutations before performing the primilaty test.